# django-filter according to the logged user

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I am using the django_filters to filtering the information. However, it is showing the data of all regitered user of my system. I need show **only** the data of logged user.

Follow the files:

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from apps.requisitos.models import Requisito

class RequisitoFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
class Meta:
model = Requisito
fields = ['nomeRequisito', 'projeto']
```

views.py

```
class RequisitoList(ListView):
paginate_by = 10
model = Requisito

def get_queryset(self):
usuarioLogado = self.request.user
return Requisito.objects.filter(user=usuarioLogado)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
context['filter'] = RequisitoFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.queryset)
return context
```

the loop for of html page

```
{% for requisito in filter.qs %}
```

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the result of `get_queryset` to the `queryset` parameter:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['filter'] = RequisitoFilter(
        self.request.GET,
        queryset=self.get_queryset()
    )
    return context
```

---

> **Note**: You might want to consider using a [**`FilterView`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/views.py),
> this view implements *most* of the [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview),
> and encapsulates logic to use a `filter_class`.

Comment: It doesn´t work... It is returning all the values of all registered users in the combobox of 'projeto'

Comment: @gPxl: but that is the form itself. You should specify the queryset of the filter as well of course, by overriding its fields.